# Is it possible that we use any package in React Native with out spacifying it in package.json or npm i @packagename

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to use any package in my app without specifying in package.json or lock.json.
Is it possible ? and how?

I didn't try yet, still curious if it's possible then how.

Comment: npm install <package-name> --no-save 
but it's not recommended.

Comment: As Taron pointed out it is possible but keep in in mind if you ever upload your project to GitHub, give it to someone else or redistribute it to anyone for any reason they won't be able to run it since the package.json won't install the packages you didn't add to it. You also run the risk of forgetting what packages you installed since you won't be able to refer to the JSON. It'll also be hard to prune unneeded or no longer used dependencies since you don't have a list of them anymore. All of these reasons are why people avoid doing this